# WordPress get post using post_parent field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on WordPress and trying to get post from `wp_posts` table. But not with ID. Instead I am trying to retrieve the post with `post_parent` field.

I tried to get the post using

> get_post_field()

But It doesn't work.

> get_post()

Also work with post ID.

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_parent='217490' ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Is there any predefined function in WordPress? or how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `get_post` does not take `post_parent` argument instead it take
>   (int|WP_Post|null) and `get post field` is used to get specific post
>   fields by `post_id`; So to get post by `post_parent` you can use any
>   of the following method.

By [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

```
$args = array(
    ...
    'post_parent' => 217490,
);

$posts_array = get_posts($args);
```

By [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
    ...
    'post_parent' => 217490,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

By [`get_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)

```
$args = array(
    ...
    'post_parent' => 217490
);
$children = get_children( $args );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup! i added additional args.. its working perfectly.. Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

get_children() is function to get post from post parent.
Check below link:

[Function Reference/get children](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)